# Converting Times Between Time Zones, The conversion could not be completed

Tags: c#, timezone, utc

I am trying to convert times between time zone

```
public QueryResult<RadAcct> Query(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, DbConnection dbConection)
{
   TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");

   //date from :2/20/2017 10:28:27 AM
   DateTime from = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateFrom, tst); 

   // error here, date to : 2/21/2017 4:56:31 Am
   DateTime to = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTo, tst); 
}
```

dateFrom and dateTo Comming from different Service and value is 2/20/2017 10:28:27 AM , 2/21/2017 4:56:31 Am

i got exception :

> The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind property set correctly.  For example, when the Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local, the source time zone must be TimeZoneInfo.Local.\r\nParameter name: sourceTimeZone

Comment: How `dateTo` is initialized?  Coming from client? Coming from db? Hardcoded? Coming from other service? `Am` is intentional or typo?

Comment: Your `dateTo` doesn't seem to be valid otherwise there is no chance that it can't be converted to other time zone.

Comment: sr about that i updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DateTime.SpecifyKind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind(v=vs.110).aspx) function to set the Kind to Unspecified,

```
TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime from = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateFrom, tst); //date from :2/20/2017 10:28:27 AM

DateTime dateToUnspecified = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTo, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

DateTime to = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateToUnspecified, tst); // date to : 2/21/2017 4:56:31 Am
```

Comment: Also, you might want to figure out how your code got a `DateTimeKind.Local` attached to `dateTo` in the first place. For example, if `dateTo` was populated from a call to `DateTime.Now`, this particular answer would not be the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified From timezone. But I can't find To timezone. You can use below code to convert times between timezones.

```
        DateTime dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime("2/21/2017 04:22:27 PM");
        TimeZoneInfo fromTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
        DateTime from = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateFrom, fromTimeZone);
        TimeZoneInfo toTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
        DateTime dateTo = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(from, toTimeZone);
```

The above code is modification in your code. But you can use simpler code for doing this:

```
        DateTime dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime("2/21/2017 04:22:27 PM");
        TimeZoneInfo fromTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
        TimeZoneInfo toTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
        DateTime dateTo = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateFrom, fromTimeZone, toTimeZone);
```

I guess you just want to covert both times to UTC. The cause of the exception might be that the Kind property of dateTo is set to Local and the local timezone of the system on which the code is running is not "AUS Eastern Standard Time". If the kind of the date passed to ConvertTimeToUtc method is Local then the method will expect the sourceTimeZone parameter to match with the local timezone of the system on which the code is running.

You can set the Kind property of dateTo to UnSpecified using below code. By this you won't get exception:

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTo, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Comment: but dateFrom and dateTo is Same time zone, i have to convert it to "AUS Eastern Standard Time" time zone